# How do I give an upvote?

Tags: support, voting, up-votes

Some one gave a very useful answer and I want to reciprocate in one way or another. How do I give an upvote?

Comment: You click the gray arrow that points upwards. To demonstrate how to downvote too, I will now click the other arrow.

Comment: you need a minimum reputation first

Comment: Didn't you get a notification when you reached at [15 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up)?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/about and http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 4):

When you have reputation atleast 15, you can vote up a post, see the following image,

> [image]

For an up vote you need to click on the up arrow (circled in blue) and for a down vote you need to click on the down arrow (circled in red)

To downvote a post you require at least 125 reputation.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I'm missing something here because it seems obvious - you click the up arrow, but it won't work until you have 15 reputation (perhaps that's the limitation you're running into?)